# 'callCounter' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: javascript, typescript

With this code:

```js
  let callCounter = 0;
  callCounter += 1;
```

I get the error:

> callCounter' is assigned a value but never used.eslintno-unused-vars

How can I fix the error?

Comment: use `callCounter` variable somewhere

Comment: Good point. The error is extremely misleading - `callCounter` must surely be used to add to it. How can it be added to if without it being used?

Comment: Why might you need to create a variable that is not used? :)

Comment: I would say it is being used. How can 0 + 1 be 1 without using 0?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called your variable callCounter anywhere.

If you do,

```
  let callCounter = 0;
  callCounter += 1;
  console.log(callCounter); //Testing purpose only
```

Your lint will not complain.